# Error while trying to source a .zshrc file

Tags: zsh, homebrew

What am I doing wrong here?

```
% echo "export HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=XXXX">> ~/.zshrc;
% source ~.zshrc;
zsh: no such user or named directory: .zshrc
```

Comment: a missing `/` between `~` and `.zshrc` maybe ?

Comment: That gives me 
/Users/.zshrc:2: no such file or directory: token
/Users/.zshrc:8: parse error near `\n'

Comment: By changing the question after getting answers, this is become a little less useful.

Comment: Umm, yeah, I don't think you'd get that error with `source ~/.zshrc`. It matches `source ~.zshrc` perfectly though, so I wonder what the point of that edit was?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing `/`

Your command `source ~.zshrc` tries to lookup the home directory for a user called `.zshrc`. The `source` command would presumably attempt to execute that user's home directory - and fail.

What you probably meant was this, which looks up *your* home directory with `~` and then `source` can execute the commands in a file `.zshrc` in there.

```
 source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: correcting that gives me 
/Users/zshrc:2: no such file or directory: token
/Users/.zshrc:8: parse error near `\n'

Comment: You've broken your `$HOME` variable

Comment: I am very newb at this can you please guide me how to fix it?

Comment: Open a new terminal session on your Mac. Unexpected error messages?

Comment: still the same error 

source ~/.zshrc;
/Users/.../.zshrc:2: no such file or directory: token
/Users/.../.zshrc:8: parse error near `\n'

Comment: But now it complains about the contents of your .zshrc``: .....zshrc:2 means `error in line 2`. Please post your .zshrc.

Comment: For clarity, in your comment above, does `…` represent your username? Did you edit the `.zshrc` file on a system other than your Mac?

Comment: ....represents my username